# Increment row by 250 to copy and paste the data

Tags: vba, excel

I have 6000 data points (stock price) for a script with date, I want to copy each time 500 data points in the next sheet and want to increment it by 250 rows each time the data is selected till the row is blank. I have created a macro but I am not able to get the desired results. The index source is the sheet which contains the 6000 data points and Index data is the sheet I want to paste the data. Thanks

```
Sub rollingresults()
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As Integer

    y = 250

    Num_Counter = Worksheets("Indexsource").Range("B1").Value

    For i = 1 To Num_Counter

        Worksheets("IndexSource").Activate

        x = Range("A4:H503").Offset(y * (i - 1), 0).Select

        Selection.Copy

        Worksheets("index_data").Range("P3").Select

        Selection.PasteSpecial

        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

        Worksheets("ALM").Range("J40:M40").Select

        Selection.Copy

        Worksheets("Hist_Output").Cells(2 + (i - 1), 2).Select

        Selection.PasteSpecial

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do not use `.Copy` and `.Paste`, but direct assignments. Also use the `.Cells()` and `.Resize()` methods to select multiple cells. For example `Worksheets("Destination").Range("A2").Cells(250,1).Resize(500,20).Value = Worksheets("Source").Range("F2").Cells(750,1).Resize(500,20).Value`

Comment: By incrementing only by 250 (On a 500 row block) you would overwrite data in the destination sheet. Do you mean you want to add 250 to the last row in the destination sheet each time? Or perhaps 251to give 250 gap?

Comment: Column A has 6000 rows of data in the source sheet and want to copy 500 rows of it in the destination sheet each time with increment of 250 gap to the destination file. For eg: Copy 500 points from the source data( B2:B503) and paste it in the destination file, the next point should be B254:B753 to be copied in the destination file